# Show all users trying to connect to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to show all users that are trying to connect to a specific instance of SQL server?

I have a rogue process somewhere and I can't find it. I've also changed the sql password so now the process can't connect to the database but I would still like to stop it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the server in the Object Explorer of SSMS, and select Activity Monitor. Expand the processes section.

That will give you a list of all connections to the database and a view into what they're doing. You can kill a process by right-clicking and selecting "Kill Process".

Comment: Thanks! Will that also show a process trying to access the server with a wrong password?

Comment: I don't think so, but there should be entries in the Windows event logs for failed logins. (It will show up as an information event from MSSQLSERVER in the Applications log.)

Comment: Thanks, I will go search in there.

Comment: Just as a bit of additional info, you can also get the process list by executing the sp_who2 stored procedure.  It's often a lot quicker than the activity monitor.

Comment: @steoleary, thanks for the suggestion. I will also try it out.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to access the error log and filter only failed logins is to run the following query:

```
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'Login failed'
```

The 0 indicates that you should only search the current log (+1 to this to reference the previous logfile) the 1 indicates that you should look in the SQL Error log and the string is the message to search for.